# ffmpeg framemd5 errors with FFV1.mkv in Windows

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using framemd5 to check lossless transcoding to FFV1.mkv and am getting mismatches between my source and FFV1 files.

If I generate the framemd5 files in Windows, I get presentation timestamp mismatches on the audio between the source file and FFV1. The MD5s themselves match.

If I generate the framemd5 files for the FFV1 in Linux (WSL), everything matches just fine.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or is this just a quirk of the ffmpeg/FFV1/Windows combination?

I am using ffmpeg version 2022-07-14-git-882aac99d2-full_build-www.gyan.dev in Windows and
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.sav2 in WSL.

Many thanks!

Jim

Comment: I'm curious about this myself (uses ffv1 but never tested with framemd5). Would you care to share the commands that you used to test this?

Comment: Hi kesh, thanks for your reply.

I've used the ffmpeg command: ffmpeg -i [input file path] -f framemd5 -n [output file path]

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/framemd5%20Intro%20and%20HowTo

I give the output file a suffix of _framemd5_mkv.txt for the mkv and _framemd5_mov.txt for my source mov. The framemd5 for source and ffv1 can be checked in Meld or using file comparison in cmd to make sure they match.

As above, my experience is that the framemd5 file for the FFV1.mkv, needs to be generated in Linux for there to be an exact match where there should be one.